# Adding elements to vectors safely from C++11 threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector, memory-management

My program needs to generate a large number of sample strings and since generating the strings is computationally intensive, I want to parallelize the process. My code is like this:

```
mutex mtx;

void my_thread(vector<string> &V, int length)
{
     string s=generate_some_string(length);  //computationally intensive part

      mtx.lock();
       V.push_back(s);
      mtx.unlock();


}

int main()
{
   vector<string> S;

   while(S.size()<1000)
  {
    vector<thread> ths;
    ths.resize(10);

    for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
       ths[i]=thread(my_thread,ref(S),100 );
    }

    for(auto &th: ths)  th.join();


  }  


}
```

I get the "Double free or corruption" error when I run it.

Comment: `generate_some_string` is missing.  Your problem is in there I believe.  Your use of mutex is fine-grained, exception unsafe, and a performance bottleneck possibly, but not wrong.

Comment: Having a fully-functional code would make this much easier to help with.

Comment: Agreed the actual vector access seems well-protected. It may be easier to use an array of std::future's though.

Comment: The function is from a scientific C library and I don't know its internal workings. It is possible that it uses non-automatic memory allocation. It didn't cross my mind that this could be the cause.

Comment: you might need a deallocator then? though, the error sounds like something was deallocated twice

Comment: I recommend you reserve your vector of string to minimize the duration on the lock. I would also recommend using `std::lock_guard` or `std::unique_lock` to manage the locking of the mutex in an exception-safe way. An addition suggestion would be to avoid recreating your threads each iteration. The overhead may exceed the gains of parallelizing.

Comment: `std::string`s default allocator does dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: I would review `generate_some_string()` function.  The rest of your code seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code**

Your use of threads looks generally correct, so the problem is likely with `generate_some_string` affecting a global state. You could fix this by either:

- Using a better library.
- Using MPI for parallelism as it will spawn processes which have separate memories.

**Parallelism Philosophy**

The above seems obvious in retrospect, so there's a question as to why it wasn't immediately apparent. I think this has something to do with the way you're achieving parallelism.

C++11 threads gives you a lot of flexibility, but it also requires that you construct your parallelism explicitly. Most of the time this is *not* what you want. It's easier, and less buggy, to give the compiler information about how it can parallelize your code and let it take care of the low-level details.

The following shows how you can do this using OpenMP: an industry-standard set of compiler-directives included in all modern compilers and used extensively in high-performance computing.

You'll notice that the code is generally easier to read than what you've written and, hence, easier to debug.

All code below will be compiled with the command (modified appropriately for your compiler:

```
g++ -O3 main.cpp -fopenmp
```

**Solution 0: Use an easier form of parallelism**

First off, I'd suggest using OpenMP for your parallelism. It's an industry standard, eliminates much of the pain of having to deal with threads, and allows you to express parallelism at a conceptual level.

**Solution 1: Private Memory**

You could solve your problem by having each thread write to its own private memory and then merging the private memories together. This avoids the mutex entirely, which may result in faster code and possibly avoids the problem you're experiencing altogether.

Note that each thread is producing multiple computationally-intensive strings, but that this work is automatically divided between the available threads. It is

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <omp.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

const int STRINGS_PER_LENGTH = 10;
const int MAX_STRING_LENGTH  = 50;

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

//Computationally intensive string generation. Note that this function
//CANNOT have a global state, or the threads will maul it.
std::string GenerateSomeString(int length){
  double sum=0;
  for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2ms);
    sum+=std::sqrt(i);
  }
  return std::to_string(sum);
}

int main(){
  //Build a vector that contains vectors of strings. Each thread will have its
  //own vector of strings
  std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > vecs(omp_get_max_threads());

  //Loop over lengths
  for(int length=10;length<MAX_STRING_LENGTH;length++){
    //Progress so the user does not get impatient
    std::cout<<length<<std::endl;
    //Parallelize across all cores
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<STRINGS_PER_LENGTH;i++){
      //Each thread independently generates its string and puts it into its own
      //private memory space
      vecs[omp_get_thread_num()].push_back(GenerateSomeString(length));
    }
  }

  //Merge all the threads' results together
  std::vector<std::string> S;
  for(auto &v: vecs)
    S.insert(S.end(),v.begin(),v.end());

  //Throw away the thread private memory
  vecs.clear();
  vecs.shrink_to_fit();
}
```

**Solution 2: Use reductions**

We can define a custom reduction operator to merge vectors. Using this operator in the parallel part of our code allows us to eliminate the vector of vectors and the clean-up afterwards. Instead, as the threads complete their work, OpenMP safely handles combining their results.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <omp.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

const int STRINGS_PER_LENGTH = 10;
const int MAX_STRING_LENGTH  = 50;    

//Computationally intensive string generation. Note that this function
//CANNOT have a global state, or the threads will maul it.
std::string GenerateSomeString(int length){
  double sum=0;
  for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2ms);
    sum+=std::sqrt(i);
  }
  return std::to_string(sum);
}

int main(){
  //Global vector, must not be accessed by individual threads
  std::vector<std::string> S;

  #pragma omp declare reduction (merge : std::vector<std::string> : omp_out.insert(omp_out.end(), omp_in.begin(), omp_in.end()))

  //Loop over lengths
  for(int length=10;length<50;length++){
    //Progress so the user does not get impatient
    std::cout<<length<<std::endl;
    //Parallelize across all cores
    std::vector<std::string> private_memory;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(merge: private_memory)
    for(int i=0;i<STRINGS_PER_LENGTH;i++){
      //Each thread independently generates its string and puts it into its own
      //private memory space
      private_memory.push_back(GenerateSomeString(length));
    }
  }
}
```

**Solution 3: Use `critical`**

We can eliminate the reduction entirely by placing the `push_back` into a critical section, which limits access to that part of the code to a single thread at a time.

```
//Compile with g++ -O3 main.cpp -fopenmp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <omp.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

const int STRINGS_PER_LENGTH = 10;
const int MAX_STRING_LENGTH  = 50;    

//Computationally intensive string generation. Note that this function
//CANNOT have a global state, or the threads will maul it.
std::string GenerateSomeString(int length){
  double sum=0;
  for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2ms);
    sum+=std::sqrt(i);
  }
  return std::to_string(sum);
}

int main(){
  //Global vector, must not be accessed by individual threads
  std::vector<std::string> S;

  //Loop over lengths
  for(int length=10;length<50;length++){
    //Progress so the user does not get impatient
    std::cout<<length<<std::endl;
    //Parallelize across all cores
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<STRINGS_PER_LENGTH;i++){
      //Each thread independently generates its string and puts it into its own
      //private memory space
      const auto temp = GenerateSomeString(length);
      //Only one thread can access this part of the code at a time
      #pragma omp critical
      S.push_back(temp);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Using an API that predates C++11 to solve a c++11 question doesn't seem a good way forward.

Comment: @GemTaylor: I'm not sure that I understand your comment. I'm using an industry-standard multi-core parallelism technique that's standard to all current compilers and is both well-regarding and widely used in high-performance computing. Its latest release was well after C++11's.

Comment: C++11 threads give you great flexibility, but OP does not seem to need that. The result is needless suffering. In any case, the technique I discuss first applies to C++11 threads, the OP will just have to incur pain to use them.

Comment: The problem is not in the synchronization of the vector.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I interpret the OP as associating the parallelism and threading with the problem. Insofar as the use of complex, user-specified parallelism makes it more difficult to find the real problem, the parallelism is the problem.